# ASP.Net pages - cache only images

Tags: asp.net, image, caching, web-config

I am working on applying caching to a set of ASP.Net pages. My question is, can I apply caching only to the images on these pages? If so, how can I do this? I would like to do this without touching the web.config if possible. I have a masterpage that is used on all of the pages that I need to cache.

I was trying to use this, but I couldn't find a way to cache only image files.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the HTTP Expires Response header in IIS to cache static content for your web pages.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28v=ws.10%29.aspx